# Crontab @reboot is not working

Tags: linux, ansible, cron

Am having this command in crontab, added using Ansible cron module.
"@reboot supervisord -c *conffilepath", but this is not working as part of reboot. But working fine while executing manually, and supervisor is starting fine. Any idea why the @reboot command not working at server reboot?

Flavour of linux: Red Hat Enterprise (6.6)

Comment: "Why cron does not do what I think it should do?" is not a programming question. Unix.SE or SuperUser are the proper sites to ask, not StackOverflow. And it has nothing to do with Ansible, it would have if the crontab entry added was different from the entry expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the path variable not loaded while executing crontab jobs. Hence just did some modification in the command and done the trick.

E.g: *$supervisordpath/supervisord -c $supervisorconfpathlocation/supervisord.conf

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

And please note that @reboot only works after a reboot. If you start the server after a shutdown or after server crashes, it doesn’t get run.